# Ogm Filter for ver 3.0.1 isn't compatible with filter from earlier version (2.3.1)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

We widely use Filters in our base libraries. After upgrading neo4j (from 3.2.0 to 3.3.0) and ogm accordingly (from 2.1.3 to 3.0.1) I found out that constructor `Filter(propertyName, propertyValue)` doesn't exist anymore.

Now I got a compilation error in our old code:

> Filter filter = new Filter(key, ob)--> The constructor Filter(String,
>   Object) is undefined

Probably, I could try to change the constructors call, but I don't know which one of `ComparisonOperator` is default in the case. Can't find any doc describing the convention. Which one should I use when, for example, I try to "find by property" in database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this constructor has been removed in OGM 3 to make the code mode explicit. In this case the replacement for

```
new Filter(propertyName, propertyValue)
```

would be

```
new Filter(propertyName, ComparisonOperator.EQUALS, propertyValue);
```

Maybe you can deal with it by using a regex like :

```
new Filter\(([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^\)^,]+)\)
```

replaced by

```
new Filter\($1, ComparisonOperator.EQUALS, $2)
```